# transparent hair texture for the BGE

Tags: texturing, game-engine, materials, transparency

I'm trying to create polygon hair like **final fantasy characters** in blender for **blender game engine** can someone help me out in creating good quality texture with z-transparency I have already tried with alpha texture maps but it do not display properly when I run the game.

Comment: For more personal help, come to our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) where we can communicate realtime.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you display alpha maps, but I'm sorry I can't help you with the hair specifically.

## Displaying alpha textures in the BGE

**Step 1**

Set the scene shading to "GLSL". Alpha textures don't work in the default "MultiTexture" setting. If you create a new game scene, you will have to repeat this step.

[image]

**Step 2**

Add transparency to your material!!! Unless you specifically tell blender, it won't know how to use the alpha you've given it. Check the "Transparency" option under the material tab, set it to "z-trace" and pull the drag bar all the way down to zero (0).

[image]

**Step 3**

Now you need to make some changes to the texture settings of your object. Assuming you've already given the material a texture, you only need to do a few things:

- Enable "Use Alpha"
- Enable "Alpha" under the "influence" tab

[image]

Comment: Note: Semi-transparency works in multi-texture mode too. But the material settings slightly differ.